# LibGDX make the world move and the player not

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm working on a simple game with libGDX and want to make the main character to be fixed in the center of the screen and the world move when I press a button. I was wondering how to do... I was thinking to add a physicsBody to the world that contains other bodies and apply impulses to it when the button is pressed, is this possible in libGDX? And if it is, can i apply other impulses or forces to the bodies contained in the world's physicsBody? I think this way would be the best for me if it is possible, because i have to work a lot with physics, but if you have other ideas tell me please

Comment: [`OrthographicCamera`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IbH_1YSynFA) because you can move the camera, thus changing the world.

Comment: could you provide some example of your code?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to think about applying forces to all the non-character objects, that's just going to get messy very quickly.

The simple solution is to move your camera so that it always looks at your character. So your game loop may look something like:-

1. Process input
2. Update physics, character and other entity positions.
3. Move camera to point at character's new position.
4. Render

This way, you can update your game world without having to think about the camera at all. Then, when it comes to rendering, you can position your camera and render your graphics without needing to know anything about the game physics. It keeps the physics and rendering relatively independent, and makes it much easier to change things in the future.

For example, you may later decide that you want the camera to follow your character for the most part, but then follow a baddy whilst it is their turn. This is now easy to do, you just specify the character / entity to look at in your game logic, and then position the camera to look at whatever target that is, before you render.

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly. i didn't think to the most simple solution :)